# Objects as Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have created array for object and now it is showing null pointer exception

```
attributes attrs1[]=new attributes[6];

attrs1[0].setKey1("processor");
attrs1[0].setValue1("i3");

attrs1[1].setKey1("ram");
attrs1[1].setValue1("256mb");

attrs1[2].setKey1("display");
attrs1[2].setValue1("15");
```

Comment: Learn and follow the Sun Java coding standards.  That class name should be Attributes, not attribute.

Answer (score 9):

Allocating an array only makes room for the individual objects, it does not allocate them

You need to explicitly do a new for each index in your array.

Comment: i want to set key as well as value so how would i do that

Comment: You need to have `attrs1[0]= new attrs1(); attrs1[1]=new attrs1()...` before working with setKey1() and setValue1()

Answer (score 2):

You also have to initialize the inner instances of the array:

```
attributes attrs1[]=new attributes[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  attrs1[i] = new attributes();
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot make objects of an array instead you should mak an array of objects...so you need make objects of all the array elements using a loop.....

```
l00p
{
attrs[i]=new attribute()
}
```